# Docker image with PHP, Composer and Docker installed

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use Gitlab.com for my CI using their shared docker runners. I have a project which requires PHP and composer installed, while it also needs docker to build a docker image of the project.

I've tried for hours to build a docker image which has PHP, composer and docker installed, but I can't seem to figure it out.

For reference, my gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this;

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

composer:install:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - /
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume $PWD:/app composer install

build:image:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - composer:install
  script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u $REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/accountname/projectname/develop .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/accountname/projectname/develop
```

Using the sample build script provided by Stefan below, I put together the following build file which appears to work perfectly. It builds the project using the project Dockerfile, and pushed the resulting image to my Gitlab repository.

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker run --rm --volume $PWD:/app composer install

build:image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u $REGISTRY_USERNAME -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/accountname/projectname/develop .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/accountname/projectname/develop
```

Comment: Why do you need Docker in the image? (Or Composer even for that matter - but that shouldn't be an issue.) Can you post what you've tried and any specific errors?

Comment: I need composer so that Gitlab CI can download the latest dependencies into the file structure, and I need docker to be able to build an image from the Dockerfile in the root of the project (which doesn't have docker or composer in it)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 2 job CI and use the [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) feature provided by Gitlab to pass the `composer install` result as [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies) between jobs.

Your first job (`composer:install`) could use something like https://hub.docker.com/r/library/composer/ in your script section to install all composer packages, then pass it to the `build:image` job that builds your Docker image.

This would roughly look like this:

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

services:
- docker:dind

composer:install:
  stage: composer
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - /
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
  - docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume $PWD:/app composer install

build:image:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
  - composer:install
  script:
  - docker build -t myimage:latest .
```

Where your `Dockerfile` could be something like this (based on [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)):

```
FROM php:7.0-cli
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "php", "./your-script.php" ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, but gitlab throws an error with the yml file telling me that composer:install is not defined in prior stages. I've added the gitlab.ci file to my question

Comment: Exact error is "build:image job: dependency composer:install is not defined in prior stages"

Comment: I managed to alter your sample a little and get something working, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the adjustments so I can apply them for a correct answer for future users with the same issue?

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've put the working script in my question.